# Unable to lock screen orientation in 21.10

Tags: 21.10, display-rotation, orientation

I recently upgraded from 21.04 to 21.10 using the `do-release-upgrade` command. One minor nuisance I've encountered is the screen orientation occasionally switching from landscape to portrait when I'm moving the laptop around. In 21.04, I was able to lock the orientation easily using a button in the system menu. This button is absent in 21.10 on the same machine.

Looking for an alternative way to lock the orientation, I found the keyboard shortcut `Super` + `O`. It looked like it worked at first, as an OSD icon came up with a padlock, and checking with `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchscreen orientation-lock` returned `true`. But when I tried turning the laptop, the orientation still changed. I tried "unlocking" using the same shortcut again and relocking, but the same result every time.

The laptop in question is an Asus Zenbook Flip; the screen can be opened all the way so it can be used like a tablet. I don't normally use the laptop in this pseudo-tablet configuration, but I've now found that the screen lock works (and the button to lock appears in the system menu) when the screen is in tablet mode, and it appears that this is what is being toggled when I lock and unlock using `Super` + `O`. So is there a separate lock setting for the screen in the normal laptop mode?